# Flutter BLoC Login authentication

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm building Login page for my app, with Bloc.
i think i did everything correct, because i don't have any error in my bloc folder.
my problem is that i can't see my Fields, login button and. etc
I mean i can't even navigate to Login page
i provide some image about my problem , and i have done done

[Picture of my Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nQe3.png)

[Picture of my Login Form Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6U5o.png)

[Picture of my username page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBeZA.png)

[Picture of my Login Bloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqqCN.png)

[Picture of my Login Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csMfF.png)

[Picture of my Login State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZX5Y.png)

[Picture of my Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H83oi.png)

i did send my action in the above images.

Comment: NO CODE IN PICTURES please.

Answer (score 0):

You have used Expanded above your Column widget in loginForm screen. Expanded should only be used as a direct child of Row, Column or Flex.
You can refer to the flutter documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html?ref=fun4code&gclid=Cj0KCQiAyKurBhD5ARIsALamXaFzn1051dJ1KI5Hq6DRPC8U184-_exj0WjzSkqvsqbPeeQ10RjSqA0aArq1EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

Due to this, error such as:

> Incorrect use of parent data widget

must be throwing in the console which wont allow your UI to render.